# How to click on toggle Full Screen button in a Map.My Map is similar to the link that i have added in the question

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, ui-automation

I have a Map where I need to click on the Toggle Full Screen button

What I have Tried:

I used the Actions Class to click on the Toggle button and is not working and have also used JavaScript Executor to click on the button but not happening .
Map Link - http://beta.findtoilet.dk/?term=2&lat=55.678937&lng=12.575738&zoom=15&maptype=roadmap
Below is my Script:

```
WebElement togglefullscreen = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'gm-fullscreen-control')]"));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", togglefullscreen);
```

**HTML:**

```
<button draggable="false" aria-label="Toggle fullscreen view" title="Toggle fullscreen view" type="button" class="gm-control-active gm-fullscreen-control" style="background: none rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; text-transform: none; appearance: none; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; user-select: none; border-radius: 2px; height: 40px; width: 40px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; right: 0px;">
```

Outer HTML:
...

Loading...
Loading...Loading...

**Can I get information on this**

Comment: Cab you share a link to web page?

Comment: @Prophet - Sorry iam not supposed to share the link

Comment: Can you share more outer HTML ?

Comment: added @cruisepandey

Comment: the outer html does not any button in it.

Comment: i got it wrong actually the html which i had given first is the one pointing to the toggle button and outerhtml is the entire map

Comment: you can give me entire page resource ?

Comment: @cruisepandey have added

Comment: nope, negative, it does not have any button in it as well

Comment: When i inspect the toggle button it gives the html as added under html so that is the html for toggle for sure

Answer (score 0):

try this css :

```
button[title='Toggle fullscreen view']
```

also, ideally as you are saying, it's in a map, we may need to change the locator.